# Page numbers in pdf using mpdf library

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using mpdf library for creating pdf files, but I have problem - when I'm using @page in css, then {PAGENO} doesn't work - in all pages this is substituted with '1'. When I remove @page from css, then everything is  ok - pages are counting.
In documentation [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=109) I found a sentence:

> Page numbering changes are made when adding a new page using AddPage() or  (or TOCpagebreak() and  ) or using @page.

Maybe someone knows how to solve it?

Comment: You say that when you remove @page it works ok. So you have the solution to your problem ? or else what is the problem ? can you clarify ?

Comment: Yes, if I remove @page, it works, but I'm using @page and @page:first for formating whole document. For example: 
`@page {
    background: url("../images/lursoft_bg.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    footer: html_mainfooter;
    header: html_mainheader;
}`

Comment: Never seen this problem before so I have no off-the-box answer. Are you on the latest version of mpdf ? Does it work if you remove the @ page :first and leave the @ page ? Can't you just do away with these two css-rules ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest verson of mpdf and I have to remove both - @page and @page:first for pages to count :( Maybe the reason is becauce I have `footer: html_mainfooter` in @page?

Comment: Possibly. If you remove the **footer: html_mainfooter; header: html_mainheader;** how does it go ?

Comment: Hmm, if I remove them, then I have no header or footer. This `$mPDF->SetHTMLFooter ('{PAGENO}/{nb}');` does nothing at all. :(

Comment: We'll no further clues really. Maybe try the fpdf web site for support. See  http://www.mpdf1.com/forum . Good luck.

Comment: @rtome thanks for advices, I'll keep diging :)